# Display non-hidden files in the current directory

Tags: linux, unix

Can someone tell me how to display "non-hidden files" in the current directory that I am. What about if I want to specify for a certain extension?

Thank you,

Comment: `ls *.ext`. `man ls` also helps

Comment: Only files starting with a dot are not shown in an `ls` invocation unless you pass `-a`, like `.bashrc` -- do you mean those files, or is your desktop environment hiding other files as well?

Comment: I am just asking to display the non-hidden files. hidden files are not to be shown

Comment: This question confuses me.  What are you doing right now to "display files" if not `ls`?  Simply running `/bin/ls` with no arguments does exactly what you want, so I don't understand what it is you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

By non-hidden files I assume you mean non-`dot` files. You could use `ls`. For a certain extension, you could use for example:

`ls *.txt`

[Linux and Unix ls command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uls.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to use the following command:
        ls --ignore=.* -l